# Bootstrap 4 Card Slider and Half slider have the same navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Whenever I navigate on my Card slider, my half slider (separate carousel) also moves. But it's interesting that it does not happen the other way around. When I navigate my half slider, my Card slider does not move. I think it has something to do with my Javascript but I don't know how to separate them in classes so they work separately since the half slider has a separate code for navigation.

1. Attached are the code, I just put parts of my html code for the half slider and card slider and the javascript that I think is causing the problem.
   [Half Slider.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAiiL.png)

   [Card Slider.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36cWH.png)

   [JScript.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVd4f.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript, your jQuery click event handlers trigger a function which targets any element with the class 'carousel' which exists in both sliders.

The reason why your half slider doesn't do the same thing is because it uses data-slide instead of the jQuery click event (which targets the 'next' and 'previous' classes).

Comment: First of all, thank you. So all I have to do is, use data-slide instead of a jQuery click event so they function separately?
With my current code, how do I go about altering my jQuery such that it only affects my cardslider?

Comment: naa, the easier solution would just to add unique IDs to your card slider's next and previous. So like id="cardNext" and then instead of $('.next') you would have $('#cardNext')